# Read from mac clipboard or text file into FileMaker variable

Tags: macos, filemaker

I would like to read either the contents of the clipboard or the contents of a locally saved text file directly into a variable in a FileMaker script. I realize that there is a script step called Paste() which will read from the clipboard and load the contents into a field. However, I am writing a script that will be used in many different databases and I will not be able to modify the structure of these databases in order to have access to a specific field.

I have FileMaker 11, but tips for any version of FileMaker could be helpful.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to read either the contents of the clipboard or the
>   contents of a locally saved text file directly into a variable in a
>   FileMaker script.

Neither is possible using purely native FileMaker tools. Not directly.

Indirectly, you could paste the contents of the clipboard into a global text field, then set a variable to the contents of the global field. And a text file could be imported.

Note that a global field can be in any table and still be accessible from anywhere in your solution.

Alternatively, you could utilize a plugin. e.g. the (free) [Base Elements plugin](http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements/plugin). Or perhaps use OS-level scripting to accomplish either one of the two described tasks (though I don't know of a way to pass a value from AppleScript *directly* into a variable).

Comment: OS scripting will have to get data back to FileMaker. On a Mac, it is done by setting a field and on Windows even this option is missing, so often the clipboard and Paste are used to get data back to FileMaker. This is what OP is trying to avoid. You can use a Web Viewer or curl fmp url to get data back, but none of them are robust and quite a bit of work.

Comment: "*OS scripting will have to get data back to FileMaker. On a Mac, it is done by setting a field*" Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I went with the solution of having global fields, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the import script step. It really depends on the data which you are trying to import. With this you can import the data into one field and then parse through it. Also insert from url will work with importing into a field. The url doesn't need to be a www but can be the file location such as file:///Users/user1/Desktop/test.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are probably the best option. You can try free 2empowerFm Clipboard Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the general opinion in our department is to avoid PlugIns.